# Voltage regulator IC capabilites

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit

I want to convert unregulated 10-14V DC to 5V DC and 12V DC regulated(constant) supply;[This](http://www.ti.com/product/lm2576) is a buck step down regulated voltage supply IC it outputs the voltage that I require. Is this IC all I need? Or there will be some more components needed?

Will this IC have:

1. Under-voltage and short-circuit protection.
2. Thermal shutdown prevents damage from overheating.
3. Reverse-voltage protection.

I have seen buck step down regulators which have many more components, than just a IC. For example this: http://www.pololu.com/product/2110. What is the use of other components, Are all the other components used to provide the above mentioned 3 points?

Comment: What about the current needed to be supplied by the outputs to their respective loads?

Comment: Do the application notes for that chip, or the example circuits in its datasheet, show additional components?

Comment: @Andyaka What about it ? I will be providing power to circuit using a standard 12V 3.3A DC adapter.

Comment: Power out to the load - read what I asked again - I never mentioned power in.

Comment: The current needed to be supplied is around 3A.

Comment: @rajat - see the addition I made to my answer

Comment: Please capitalize "I" when referring to yourself. Also you do not need a space before punctuation such as a question mark. I've left similar comments before. These things help make your question more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting 5V from a supply that is ranging from 10V to 14V is no problem for the LM2576 and it has thermal and current limit protection.It doesn't have under-voltage-lock-out but it does have an on-off pin that can be used (with an external circuit) to provide this function.

[image]

It doesn't have reverse input voltage protection either - you should consider using a diode for this.

Getting 12V from a supply that ranges from 10V to 14V is more complicated and you can do this with a buck-boost type controller. Buck on its own can only produce voltages that are smaller than its input voltage - that is why the 5V is relatively easy. Note that there is a section in the LM2576's data sheet that talks about buck-boost but this is to produce a negative output voltage only and you should not get confused with the device - it cannot produce a boosted positive output easily.

You could use the LM2576 to produce 5V then have a boost regulator on the 5V output to produce 12V - boost regulators do what they say - they boost the voltage output and therefore the input supply voltage to them needs to be below the output voltage they produce.

Regarding the other device linked - without a circuit diagram it's guesswork as to what all the components do - UVLO would hardly account for anything more than two resistors on a lot of chips available (such as Linear Technology's offerings) and reverse voltage protection can be achieved with a maximum of three components usually.

The [LT1074](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1074fds.pdf) can supply 5A at 5V and, given your input power is able to supply 3.3A, the 1074 may be more suitable: -

[image]

It's got enough capability to tee it's output to a boost regulator for the 12V rail providing you manage the output load currents. There's also the LT8471 that can provide two outputs - this picture shows the general idea: -

[image]

The negative 12V supply is easily made a positive supply - read the data sheet if you are interested.

Comment: Hmm, regarding the under-voltage lockout I am just wondering why its `Vth = Vz1 + 2*Vbe`. I would've said just `Vz1 + Vbe`.

Comment: @Rev1.0 yeah I agree - I'm confused as well - can't see why it is 2Vbe.

Comment: @Rev1.0 I bet the 10k and 20k resistors have something to do with this - if both were 10k then I could see it being 2Vbe!